# Invalid Validation exception occuring on submit in ASP.NET app page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

This is a completely out-of-the-box perspective on another question I've posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19428300/tinymce-not-posting-edited-value-even-after-triggersave-in-asp-net-app) in the thought that I may be attributing the problem to the wrong source (which is, in that question, related to TinyMCE). It occurred to me the problem may be more organic, and that I'm looking at it entirely incorrectly.

An otherwise unremarkable page in a particular ASP.NET application includes a form with an ASP:TextBox control that is initialized to a particular value that includes HTML markup. The textbox is set for multiline operation and is rendered as an HTML textarea. The user changes that value and submits the page (via an appropriate button). Regardless of what the user types in the box, ASP.NET throws a validation exception on the basis *of the original value of the text box.*

Have tried setting EnableViewState on the control to false in case, somehow, the value being checked was coming out of the form's viewstate on postback. No luck.

What mechanism would cause ASP.NET to see the *previous* value held in the textbox? Running the page in the debugger clearly shows the field containing the changed value right to the time the submit is called against the host form.

Perhaps the solution or cause is obvious, and I'm just having a severe case of concerete-between-the ears, but I'm plainly not seeing it.

Comment: Generally, ASP.NET has access to the previous value of a control before a postback via the ViewState property (although this depends on each control's implementation). You can set the `EnableViewState` to `false` property on the text box to see if this is what is causing your issue, but it would be extemely weird if it was.

Comment: Thanks, welegan! Definitely thought of that, and disabled viewstate for the control. Should add that as a "tried this." Good catch.

Comment: Where is the validation taking place? Client or server?

Comment: This is a server validation exception - ASP.NET's check for HTML injection attacks.